# public Web access to companys Application database

Tags: mysql, database-connection, security

im struggling to find the best practice to this so any links or research reading materials or any Google search terms will be much appreciated.

Im a volunteer for a local charity organization, a childcare setting.

We have a mysql database that contains various tables containing children & Parent information, invoices, staff rotas etc.

What we would like to attempt to do is have secure online access for parents to view there own contact details and invoices.

My question is, is it safe to allow the website to have access to the main database. it would be a second set of userPermisions with only read access to select tables and not the entire database.
I don't want the website to open up a hole to allow users to obtain all our data or destroy or corrupt the main database.

Or

should i create a second database that the website will have access to and have the main database sync with the second? I can see future issues if we decide to allow parents to edit there own contact details, pay invoices online.

Web specific details will be kept in a second database such as user name password, forum etc

Its not any thing iv ever attempted to do before and don't know where to start in terms of research.

Kind regards

Matt

Comment: You are going to have to build an application on top of the database. That application will have to be watertight, and make it absolutely sure nothing of what you describe can happen. What language(s) are currently being used to enter data into the database?

Comment: The desktop application for office staff is currently c# .net whilst the website will be developed in php

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You certainly couldn't **hurt** anything by having a second, slave/read-only database accessible to your user interface.  If done properly, [MySQL grants](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/grant.html) can restrict users to read-only operations, so it's not **necessary** from a functional standpoint to have a second database.  Perhaps, given the nature of your business, there may be a **legal** reason why you must have a second database though.  Be sure to investigate the [requirements for protecting PII](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Personally_identifiable_information#United_States_of_America) (e.g. HIPPA)

Comment: Thanks, that's what i wanted to know. Iv made plenty of sites before but nothing where mission critical data has been opened up to the public via a website.

Comment: @user330403 - Glad  I could help.  On this site, it's customary to "accept" an answer if you feel it is the best one.  Just click the checkbox next to the answer.  Also, click the up arrow to "upvote" the answer.  Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Security is an ongoing process - part of it is ensuring proper identification and authorization as well as defense in depth - ensuring that the account used to access the database has least privileges and that the surface area exposed to that account is minimal.  Also if the database is on the same machine as the web server, then ensuring that a compromise of the web server doesn't also compromise the database.

You also have to contend with the standard social elements - ensuring users have a way to get their first password/setup an account, maintain their own passwords.  You should not store their passwords (even encrypted), but instead store only a salted hash.  When they forget their password, the reset it themselves, since the web site cannot and should not send them a permanent password via email.

And you should be aware of XSS (cross-site scripting attacks), SQL injection - you should be able to find references to that in most discussions of web application development.

Comment: Thanks for the reply, I will be using the yiiFramework and HTMLPurifier to try and keep the site secure.  My Friend  is a web developer and has agreed to check over the pages for any obvious issues.